# Taking user input in a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been converting a console maze game I made to a Winform and am having errors when trying to take the user input. When I was making the console game I used

```
Console.Read();
ConsoleKeyInfo press = Console.ReadKey(true);    
press.Key == ConsoleKey.DownArrow;
```

However as it is now a winform app, rather than a console app I cannot get input this way, so instead of doing this i have been attempting to get the input by creating an instance of the form, and then an instance of the keyeventhandler, like so

```
public static gameBorder FormInstance;
public event KeyEventHandler KeyDown;
```

and calling this in another class within a comparative statement like so:

```
if(gameBorder.FormInstance.KeyPress += Keys.W )
```

Yet this throws the error:

> cannot implicitly convert type system.windows.forms.keys to system.windows.form.keypresseventhandler

I am thinking that it is because i am trying to compare an instance of a key event handler with a key being pressed, yet am unsure. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: `if(gameBorder.FormInstance.KeyPress += Keys.W )` is **not** a "comparative statement". You are **not** "trying to compare" things, `+=` is an addition assignment operator. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx for a start. Did you even try to read on the very basics before asking the question?

Comment: @KonradMorawski my apologies.

Comment: there is no need for apologies :) I'm sorry if my comment was condescending. I still think it's better to pick up some theory to get you started, otherwise you will learn more slowly

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
gameBorder.FormInstance.KeyPress +=
```

Is how you subscribe an event handler. `Keys.W` is not an event handler.

Visual Studio will do you a huge favor an add a new event handler for you when you type that `+=`. Go ahead and let it do so, and then you can test what key was pressed inside the function it generates (using [`KeyPressEventArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)).

Assign the event handler:

```
gameBorder.FormInstance.KeyPress += HandleKeyPress;
```

Handle the event:

```
private void HandleKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyChar == 'W')
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll suggest adding `Form1_KeyPress` to the first code block to make it clear

Comment: Thank you @Jon B. I have been struggling with this concept for hours. I can now edit my code so that when W is pressed i set a local var, which i can use as a parameter.